# Security Exception: no permissions for indices:data/read/mget encountered after login to Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, openshift-origin, fluentd

I am facing an issue while trying to deploy EFK stack in an openshift 3.9~  cluster of single master,etcd and node.The EFK pods are successfully deployed and are in running state.
When I try to login to kibana dashboard as developer/developer (who is a cluster-admin) I get the following error in the console

```
Error: unhandled courier request error: [security_exception] no permissions for indices:data/read/mget
at handleError (https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:98251:23)
at DocRequest.AbstractReqProvider.AbstractReq.handleFailure (https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:98171:15)
at https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:98065:18
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:98063:19
at processQueue (https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:42452:29)
at https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:42468:28
at Scope.$eval (https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:43696:29)
at Scope.$digest (https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:43507:32)
at Scope.$apply (https://kibana.openshiftmaster.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=10229:43804:25)
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: I upgraded my cluster to 3.11 and now I am able to log in to the  Kibana console without issues.